# Angular & Loopback : User.login is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, loopbackjs

So, I got an error today when I try to run Login function in Ionic.

**The error said : TypeError: User.login is not a function** (on controller.js

This is my controller.js :

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, User, $state) {
        $scope.signIn = function(user) {
        $scope.loginResult = User.login(user,
        function(res) {
        console.log('Login success');
        console.log(res);
        $state.go('tab.dash');
        // success
        }, function(res) {
        // error
        });

    }
})
```

and this is my login.html :

```
       <div class="list list-inset">
              <label class="item item-input">
                  <input type="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="user.email">
              </label>
              <label class="item item-input">
                  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password">
              </label>          
          </div>
          <button class="button button-block button-calm" ng-click="signIn(user)">Login</button>
```

This is my route in app.js :

```
.state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
  })
```

Please correct my code.

Thanks for ur effort :)

Comment: where is the User service - looks like there is no method called login in that service

Comment: How you mapping your controller? using routing  or ng-controller directive?Please share routing script.

Comment: Currently, I am using strongloop and it has 'login' method by default.

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN : I am using routing right now. please check my update

Comment: have you defined User services under same module 'starter.controllers' or different module ?If it is have injected that module ?

Comment: solved :). I just install lb-services again

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up the `loopback-sdk-angular` properly? Please see my example at https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-getting-started-intermediate/blob/master/client/js/services/auth.js#L6-L15